# Scrapy returning that: "ScrapyDeprecationWarning: '2.6' is a deprecated value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting."

Tags: python, scrapy

Having trouble getting this script to work. It's returning this error:

> ScrapyDeprecationWarning: '2.6' is a deprecated value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting.

Here is the script:

```
import scrapy

class HealthcareSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'healthcare_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.google.com/search?q=healthcare+websites+usa']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Extract search results from Google's search page
        results = response.css('div.g')
        for result in results:
            # Extract the URL of each search result
            url = result.css('a::attr(href)').get()
            # Check if the URL is a healthcare website based in the USA
            if 'healthcare' in url and 'usa' in url:
                yield {
                    'url': url,
                }
        # Follow the link to the next page of search results, if available
        next_page_url = response.css('a#pnnext::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url), callback=self.parse)
```

I tried upgrading scrapy, but that wasn't the issue. A little stuck here. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: That isn't an error it's a warning.

Answer (score 2):

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=scrapy.exceptions.ScrapyDeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an error. This is merely a warning.
Embed your crawler within the warning library to ignore this warning.

```
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
    runner = CrawlerRunner()
```